# box2d multiple fixture positioning inside single body (Physics Editor)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am trying to dynamically create the shape of a number using shape definitions from Physics Editor. I have separate shape definitions for each digit from 0-9.

I create a CCLabelBMFont with a random number (e.g. 42) and add a single body for that label. Then I loop through each child sprite of the label and add the according shape definition for that digit. The shape definition for each digit is added, but centered inside of the body (i.e. stacked on top of each other). Is it somehow possible to re-position the shapes (polygon shapes) inside of that body?

I have tried to offset each shape's position by re-setting m_centroid during the creation of the fixture with no luck (inside "GB2ShapeCache.m"):

```
-(void) addFixturesToBody:(b2Body*)body forShapeName:(NSString*)shape withXOffset:(float32)xOff{
  BodyDef *so = [shapeObjects_ objectForKey:shape];
  assert(so);

  FixtureDef *fix = so->fixtures;
  while(fix)
  {
    [...]
    b2PolygonShape* polygon = (b2PolygonShape*) fix->fixture.shape;
    polygon->m_centroid.Set(polygon->m_centroid.x + xOff, polygon->m_centroid.y);
}
```

Comment: It will be easier if you just create one body for each letter. If you need the letters to stick together, add a distance joint between each body pair.

Comment: if you want only on body then give different different anchor point to respective body fixtures.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I decided to go with a single body and instead of using predefined Physics Editor shapes, I approximated each number with multiple circle shapes (this should hopefully allow a smoother collision detection).